# Bootstrap 3 change Carousel arrows

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys i am using bootstraps Carousel options and i would like to change the arrows as i think they are ugly.

I would like to make them look like this :

[image]

However I'm not so sure how to do this, i tried to create them using CSS but i can only get the box to show up , so far i have :

HTML:

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
<span class="lnr lnr-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
<span class="lnr lnr-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
  background-image: none !important;
}

.carousel-control {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.carousel-control .lnr-chevron-left {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  background: #333333;
  top: 48%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -10px;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

.carousel-control .lnr-chevron-right {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  background: #333333;
  top: 48%;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -10px;
  float: right;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

I was using this websites Example but i cant seem to replicate it : [Link here](http://kingstudio.ro/demos/ms/single-product.html)

Any help on trying to make the arrows look like this would be great

Thanks

Comment: It actually looks like that glyph comes from `linear-icons.css`'s `.lnr` class.

Comment: @Froopy ah so there is no way of changing it? I have no idea how the guy on the other website did it

Comment: Changing it isn't the issue.  Have you copied and imported that CSS stylesheet and all of its assets?  Looking in the CSS document, there's a few fonts in there.  You're probably just missing the font files.

Comment: @Froopy I have , i got the grey box to appear perfectly but the arrows are not i have a box with the bottom line missing , so no idea why its not there

Comment: @Froopy I'm an idiot, i got it work , missing the font folder :) thanks so much xxx

Comment: No problem, I'll post my comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in the `linear-icons.css` file, I notice there is the following:

```css
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Linearicons-Free';
 src:url('../fonts/Linearicons-Free.eot?w118d');
 src:url('../fonts/Linearicons-Free.eot?#iefixw118d') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/Linearicons-Free.woff2?w118d') format('woff2'),
  url('../fonts/Linearicons-Free.woff?w118d') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/Linearicons-Free.ttf?w118d') format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/Linearicons-Free.svg?w118d#Linearicons-Free') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}

.lnr {
 font-family: 'Linearicons-Free';
 speak: none;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 text-transform: none;
 line-height: 1;

 /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Verify you have also gotten the font files as the `.lnr` class uses a font they provide.